# getValue returning object that isn't compatible with listview

Tags: firebase, vue.js, nativescript

I am using the nativescript-plugin-firebase plugin and the following function to get my data from firebase and display it in a listview component. However, it's downloading an object and I think listview wants an array. I have looked at every forum post on the web and can't figure out how to properly reformat this object into what listview wants. With vuefire for web, it was so easy, but I can't figure it out with this component. Any help would be much-appreciated.

I have tried the following:

- result.json(), which doesn't seem to work with nativescript
- JSON.parse(result)
- different variations of for loops pushing to arrays, which works, but I couldn't figure out how to properly format the array for listview.
- Object.keys(result).map(item => result[item])
- I also tried the query method in addition to the getValue method, but had no luck with that either.

```
//Here is my listview component:

<ListView class="list-group" for="getWod in getWods" @itemTap="onItemTap"
                    style="height:1250px">
                    <v-template>
                        <FlexboxLayout flexDirection="row" class="list-group-item">
                            <Label :text="getWod.workoutType" class="list-group-item-heading"
                                style="width: 60%" />
                        </FlexboxLayout>
                    </v-template>
                </ListView>


//Here is my call to the API (when I call this function, I set the returned value to "this.getWods") 

fetchRequestForGettingData(currentDate1) 
{ return firebase.getValue('/wods') 
.then(result => { return result; }) 
.catch(error => console.log("Error: " + error)); }


//Here is what is returned by my function:
key: 'wods', value: 
{ '-LWcIjtZGo-arGiWjWJd': 
{ weight: 'testing123', workoutType: 'testing123', time: 'testing123', edit: false, reps: 'testing123', date: '01-02-2019', timeCap: 'testing123', workout: 'testing123', description: 'testing123', name: 'testing123' }, 
'-LWjCMG-jNDnEudppl9J': 
{ weight: 'testing123', workoutType: 'testing123', time: 'testing123', edit: false, reps: 'testing12332', date: '02-01-2019', timeCap: 'testing123', workout: '-LWU4DWJWVJxWkDSZYw9', description: 'testing123', name: 'testing123' }, 
'-LWjEtBwIJDPHK43hVjK': 
{ weight: 'testing123', workoutType: 'testing123', time: 'testing123', edit: false, reps: 'testing12332', date: '20-01-2019', timeCap: 'testing123', workout: '-LWc289<…>
```

My expected output is an object/array that is compatible with the listview component.

Comment: Firebase already gives you a JSON Object, so you don't need to parse it. A JSON necessarily need not to be an Array, it could be any valid JavaScript Object. `this.getWods = Object.keys(result).map(item => result[item])` should have worked, please share if you have a Playground sample that makes it easy to fix this for you.

Comment: is it possible for you to create a playground ? https://play.nativescript.org/

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I haven't tried installing plugins before on playground, but looks straight forward. I appreciate the help.